# Expression Engine Safecracker Date Format Issue

Tags: date, format, expressionengine

I am having major issue with Expression Engine Date Variable Format, 
seems to be not working at all, or not sure what I am doing wrong.
very very confused at the moment, have no idea what it is going on.
I am currently using the EEvent Helper for my date fields.

My Custom Field name is: {start_date}

Well here is the code I have right now.

```
{exp:safecracker channel="channel" include_jquery="no"}
    {start_date format="%F %d %Y"}
{/exp:safecracker}
```

It is not outputting the date field or formatting it. I am just getting

```
 {start_date format="%F %d %Y"}
```

on the website, but if I removed the format, I get this: 1361174400
not quite sure what is going on.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure where the date is coming from, but I've found http://momentjs.com/ to be a huge help. You can wrap your date object and print out the date. moment(new Date()).format("M/DD/YYYY");

Comment: thanks Chris, that might be a possibility to look into, I am trying to do it in Expression Engine, it has the built in functionality

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, but I guess I found a work around which isnt very ideal
but it seems like the date format does not work well in safecracker, I changed it to

```
{exp:channel:entries} instead of {exp:safecracker}
```

and it works, but I need it to be using safecracker not channel entries but this is a "preview entry" for users if they are happy of what they have submitted, or go back to edit

this is what I put in to make it work

```
    {start_date}
    {start_date format="%F %d %Y"}
```

The output is

```
    {start_date} 1361606400
    {start_date format="%F %d %Y"} February 23 2013
```

which is very strange because you would need both of them to work, if you just put

```
 {start_date format="%F %d %Y"}
```

it will just output to the page, it would not show the date

I end up putting a css class none, to just hide it

```
    <span class="none">{start_date} 1361606400</span>
    {start_date format="%F %d %Y"} February 23 2013
```

I know this is not ideal, but been stuck on this for hours and hours, have found no solution to it
hopefully this post will help others that are having this issue.
Or if someone has found a better fix to this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is, surprisingly, still the case, even with EE2.9.2 and native safecracker (ie. exp:channel:form). I just spent the last couple hours banging my head against the wall too. Thanks Kevin! I'd have voted up your answer or commented but I need more reputation.